# How to use if query in where clause

Tags: mysql

How to change the  FOREIGN KEY using if in where clause

```
SELECT u.id,u.first_name, m.text,m.msg_id,m.u_from_id,m.u_to_id 
FROM user u 
JOIN messages m 
ON u.id= m.u_from_id 
WHERE m.ad_id=$ad_id 
    AND m.msg_id>'$last_msg_id' 
GROUP BY m.u_from_id 
ORDER BY m.u_from_id
```

This query is working perfectly, but I want some modification

**if m.u_from_id='6'**  then check **u.id=m.to_id** instead of **u.id= m.u_from_id**

(if the  FOREIGN KEY(m.u_from_id) value='6' then change the FOREIGN KEY to m.to_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `IF` in mysql as it is known from for example MS Access, the equivalent, you may want to use, is `CASE`:

```
SELECT u.id,u.first_name, m.text,m.msg_id,m.u_from_id,m.u_to_id 
FROM user u 
JOIN messages m 
ON CASE WHEN m.u_from_id = 6 THEN u.id=m.to_id ELSE u.id= m.u_from_id END
WHERE m.ad_id=$ad_id 
    AND m.msg_id>'$last_msg_id' 
GROUP BY m.u_from_id 
ORDER BY m.u_from_id
```